# Resampling 15 minutes data to 30minutes

Tags: python, date, time, aggregation, resampling

Im using the resampling function in pandas to sum up two 15 minutes interval data into 30 minutes interval data for a data frame. it works but the answer i get is just that for the results recorded at the 30th minutes , not the addition of the recorded results at the 15th and the 30th minute. Any help please?

Below is the code i used for the resampling and the results for that:
series["30mins"]= series.resample('2T',label="right",closed="right").sum()
time                    15 mins rainfall      30mins
2020-09-13 06:45:00      2.587                 nan
2020-09-13 07:00:00      2.621                 2.621
2020-09-13 07:15:00      1.617                 nan
2020-09-13 07:30:00      5.748                 5.748

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
`series["30mins"]= series.resample('2T',label="right",closed="right").sum()`

try

```
series["30mins"]= series.resample('2T').agg({'column name': 'sum'})
```

It worked for me.